# Reading from an unaligned uint8_t recast as a uint32_t array - not getting all values

Tags: cuda, alignment, memory-alignment

I am trying to cast a uint8_t array to uint32_t array. However, when i try to do this, I cant seem to be able to access every consecutive 4 bytes.

Let us say I have a uint8_t array with 8 bytes. I would like to access byte 2 -> 6 as one uint32_t.

These all get the same value `*((uint32_t*)&uint8Array[0])`, `*((uint32_t*)&uint8Array[1])`, `*((uint32_t*)&uint8Array[2])`, `*((uint32_t*)&uint8Array[3])`

While `*((uint32_t*)&uint8Array[4])` gets the bytes 4 -> 8 as expected.

So it seem like I can not access 4 consecutive bytes from any address?

Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: You can't do this.  You can only access properly-aligned words.  (Some processors might let you get away with it, but it's extra work on the processor's work, and some processors don't, and the C language does not require them to.)  If you want to do an unaligned access portably, you have to do it "by hand", as in @DietrichEpp's answer.

Comment: CUDA has very well documented alignment requirements, and all memory transactions have to be transaction sized aligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want bytes 2..6, you're going to have to combine multiple aligned loads to get what you want.

```
uint32_t *ptr = ...;
uint32_t value = (ptr[0] >> 16) | (ptr[1] << 16);
```

Technically, this is *also* the portable way to do things in C in general, but we're all spoiled because you don't have to do the extra work on x86, ARM, Power, or other common architectures.

Comment: Reinterpreting type uint8_t as a non-compatible type is undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501: If this were C, that would be the case if you use a very narrow reading of the C standard, but this is not C.  It looks very much like C so I can understand why you would think so.

Comment: If cuda doesn't use the c language, which language does it use and where can I find the specification?

Comment: @2501: I don't know where to find a CUDA specification.

Comment: Then how do you know it doesn't follow strict aliasing; where do you draw this information from?

Comment: Maybe I should present evidence since I'm making the claim. Cuda uses the C++ language without some features. Unless one of those missing features is lack of aliasing rules, which are the same in C and C++ for the purposes of this case, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @2501: Please either open a new question or address your comments to the OP.

Comment: @2501: It's particularly annoying from my perspective to have these comments attached to my answer, because I was careful to remove type punning from the code I included in the answer, and here you are complaining to me about somebody else's code.

Comment: According to the official documentation that lists missing features, aliasing rules are not missing: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#restrictions

Comment: @2501: Again, please open a new question or address your comments to the OP.  This is not the appropriate place to have a discussion about aliasing in CUDA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126431/discussion-between-dietrich-epp-and-2501).

Answer (score 7):

While unaligned accesses are not allowed in CUDA, the [`prmt` PTX instruction](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#data-movement-and-conversion-instructions-prmt) has a handy mode to emulate the effect of unaligned reads within registers. This can be exposed with a bit of [inline PTX assembly](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html). If you can tolerate a read past the end of the array, the code becomes quite simple:

```
// WARNING! Reads past ptr!
__device__ uint32_t read_unaligned(void* ptr)
{
    uint32_t result;
    asm("{\n\t"
        "   .reg .b64    aligned_ptr;\n\t"
        "   .reg .b32    low, high, alignment;\n\t"
        "   and.b64      aligned_ptr, %1, 0xfffffffffffffffc;\n\t"
        "   ld.u32       low, [aligned_ptr];\n\t"
        "   ld.u32       high, [aligned_ptr+4];\n\t"
        "   cvt.u32.u64  alignment, %1;\n\t"
        "   prmt.b32.f4e %0, low, high, alignment;\n\t"
        "}"
        : "=r"(result) : "l"(ptr));
    return result;
}
```

To ensure the access past the end of the array remains harmless, round up the number of allocated byte to a multiple of 4, and add another 4 bytes.

Above device code has the same effect as the following code on a little-endian host that tolerates unaligned accesses:

```
__host__ uint32_t read_unaligned_host(void* ptr)
{
    return *(uint32_t*)ptr;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you assuming the address is less than 2^32 - 1 ?

Comment: Also, please have a look at my answer.

Comment: Why do you think the code would fail for addresses >= 2^32? Note that only the lowest two bits of `alignment` are relevant, so a 32 bit register is more than sufficient.

Comment: Also this code is very conservative explicitly masking out the two lowest bits of the address. I don't think any Nvidia hardware currently in existence requires that.

Answer (score 0):

As @DietrichEpp suggests, you'll have to make two loads; and as @tera suggests, you can combine these two loads generically for cheap even when the misalignment is not known in advance (i.e. when the initial address of `uint8Array` is arbitrary) using the `prmt` PTX instruction.

I'll offer a solution based on @tera's which will let you do:

```
value = read_unaligned(&uint8Array[offset]);
```

safely and (relatively) efficiently. Also, it will only have one inline PTX assembly instruction, and an "unsafe" variant if you need it:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

__device__ __forceinline__ uint32_t prmt_forward_4_extract(
    uint32_t first_word,
    uint32_t second_word, 
    uint32_t control_bits)
{
    uint32_t result;
    asm("prmt.b32.f4e %0, %1, %2, %3;"
        : "=r"(result)
        : "r"(first_word), "r"(second_word), "r"(control_bits) );
    return result;
}

/*
 * This unsafe, faster variant may read past the 32-bit naturally-aligned
 * word containing the last relevant byte
 */
__device__ inline uint32_t read_unaligned_unsafe(const uint32_t* __restrict__ ptr)
{
    /*
     *  Clear the bottom 2 bits of the address, making the result aligned 
     *  for the purposes of reading a 32-bit (= 4-byte) value
     */
    auto aligned_ptr  = (uint32_t*) ((uint64_t) ptr & ~((uint64_t) 0x3));
    auto first_value  = *aligned_ptr;
    auto second_value = *(aligned_ptr + 1);

    auto lower_word_of_ptr = (uint32_t)((uint64_t)(ptr));

    return prmt_forward_4_extract(first_value, second_value, lower_word_of_ptr);
}

__device__ inline uint32_t read_unaligned(const uint32_t* __restrict__ ptr)
{
    auto ptr_is_already_aligned = ((uint64_t)(ptr) & 0x3 == 0);
    if (ptr_is_already_aligned) { return *ptr; }
    return read_unaligned_unsafe(ptr);
}
```

Comment: This looks wrong to me - you need to to pass (the lowest two bits of) the unaligned pointer for the control bits. Why don't you test your code when you've already compiled it?

Comment: @tera: Indeed, I needed to pass the lower bits of the unaligned pointer. Fixed and tested.