# Can one make unaligned loads and stores in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpgpu

Does CUDA support unaligned loads and stores? Can one naively read a (single) value of size k bytes from an address addr such that addr % k != 0?

More concretely, will accesses such as:

```
unsigned* p = (unsigned*) ((char *) my_aligned_ptr + 1); *p = 0xAABBCCDD;
```

or

```
unsigned* q = (unsigned*) ((char *) my_aligned_ptr + 11); unsigned x = *q;
```

have the expected effect?

Comment: The documentation that you linked in your now-deleted answer already answers this question.  It cannot be done.  If you simply tried your code, you would find `cuda-memcheck` reporting a misaligned error.  So that is more evidence that it does not work, regardless of how you read or whether you read the documentation.  The answer is no.  Dereference of a pointer is expected to occur on a naturally aligned boundary for the pointer, and it is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that this happens.  And I assume in your second example you meant `unsigned x = *q;`

Comment: In case someone needs to work around this limitation, I gave some [example code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40198552/1662425) to a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the [Size and Alignment Requirement subsection](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) of the CUDA Programming guide being somewhat ambiguous, the answer is **No, unaligned access is not supported, period.** The code will compile but the result will (likely) be as if some nearby aligned addresses were used. Or otherwise undefined.

@tera has work-around code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40198552/1662425).