# How to turn every bit into a byte

Tags: c++, cuda, bit-manipulation

I have the following code to turn a bit into a byte.

```
__device__ UINT64 bitToByte(const UINT8 input) {
    UINT64 b = ((0x8040201008040201ULL * input) >> 7) & 0x0101010101010101ULL; 
    //reverse the byte order <<-- this step is missing
    return b;
}
```

However the bytes are in the wrong order, the endianness is reversed.
On the CPU I can simply to a `bswap reg,reg` to fix this, but what do I do on the GPU?

Alternatively, what similar trick can I use so that the bytes are put the right way round, i.e. the Most Significant bit goes to the Most Significant Byte, such that I don't need a bswap trick.

Comment: A naive thought maybe, but can you not do the `bswap reg,reg` step first, so that the endianness is correct and then do the bit-to-byte conversion.

Comment: @JoeyMallone, I don't have a bswap instruction, all my code runs on the GPU. Hence the `CUDA` tag and the `__device__` annotation on the function.

Comment: The prmt PTX instruction allows doing this. I don't have time to find you the links now, but I've used it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40198552/1662425), which might give you just enough info to work it out yourself.

Comment: @tera, ah yess, `prmt` maps to the intrinsic `__byte_perm(a32,b32,swap)` instruction. That will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reverse byte order, the bit extraction can be done with the same trick, but by swapping the coefficients that perform the shift in the multiplication. However, to avoid clashes in the multiplication, it must be done in two steps, for the even and odd bits. This way, 2 bytes are free to hold the result of the every multiplication which is sufficient to ensure integrity of the result.

```
__device__ UINT64 bitToByte(const UINT8 input) {
  UINT64 b = ( ((0x0002000800200080ULL * input) >> 7) & 0x0001000100010001ULL) 
          |  ( ((0x0100040010004000ULL * input) >> 7) & 0x0100010001000100ULL);

    return b;
}
```

As spotted in the comments, to optimize, the shifts can be factorized.

```
__device__ UINT64 bitToByte(const UINT8 input) {
  UINT64 b =  ( ((0x0002000800200080ULL * input) & 0x0080008000800080ULL) 
              | ((0x0100040010004000ULL * input) & 0x8000800080008000ULL) )
                >> 7 ;
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I did try this, but ran into clashes with the multiplicands overflowing into the adjacent byte. This solves that.

Comment: Makes sense. In `0x8040201008040201` the 1 bits are 9 apart, but in `0x0102040810204080` they're only 7 apart. In this way you keep them 14 bits apart.

Comment: You can eliminate two operations by factoring the ` >>7` into the constants here. But the optimizer might spot that too.

Comment: @MSalters Right! But the masks must be changed and I doubt the optimizer can do that. Updated the answer with this suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @tera, here is the answer:

```
//Expand every bit into a byte
__device__ static UINT64 Add012(const UINT8 input) {
    const UINT64 b = ((0x8040201008040201ULL * input) >> 7) & 0x0101010101010101ULL; //extract every bit into a byte
    //unfortunatly this returns the wrong byte order
    UINT32* const b2 = (UINT32*)&b;
    UINT64 Result;
    UINT32* const Result2 = (UINT32*)&Result;
    Result2[0] = __byte_perm(b2[0]/*LSB*/, b2[1], 0x4567);  //swap the bytes around, the MSB's go into the LSB in reverse order
    Result2[1] = __byte_perm(b2[0]/*LSB*/, b2[1], 0x0123);  //and the LSB -> MSB reversed.
    return Result;
}
```

The [`__byte_perm` replaces the `bswap`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT_1g0b8b8156fe619205bf8d65acd8f29131) instruction.

Alternatively the input can be reversed using the [`__brev` (bit-reverse) intrinsic](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT_1gc84ef1115946870edbcebddc0d539c5a):

```
//Expand every bit into a byte
__device__ static UINT64 Add012(const UINT8 input) {
    const UINT32 reversed = (__brev(input) >> 24);
    return ((0x8040201008040201ULL * reversed) >> 7) & 0x0101010101010101ULL; //extract every bit into a byte
}
```

The second version looks easier.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reverse the result, you can reverse `input`, with any of the tricks explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602823/in-c-c-whats-the-simplest-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-bits-in-a-byte). For example, using the approach of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603254/3287591):

```
static UINT8 lookup[16] = {
    0x0, 0x8, 0x4, 0xc, 0x2, 0xa, 0x6, 0xe,
    0x1, 0x9, 0x5, 0xd, 0x3, 0xb, 0x7, 0xf, };

UINT8 reverse(UINT8 n) {
    return (lookup[n & 0xF] << 4) | lookup[n >> 4];
}

__device__ UINT64 bitToByte(const UINT8 input) {
    UINT64 b = ((0x8040201008040201ULL * reverse(input)) >> 7) & 0x0101010101010101ULL; 
    return b;
}
```

Comment: I'd really rather not use a lookup table.